# How to prove the following limit is exactly c?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to calculate the following limit
$$
\lim_{L \xrightarrow{} +\infty} \left[1 - \left(1 - \frac{c}{1 + L^{2 \gamma}}\right)^{L} \right] L^{2 \gamma - 1},
$$

where $c \in (0, 1]$ and $\gamma > 0.5$.

I used the Wolfram to numerically calculate it, and found that the limit is exactly $c$. But I don't know how to theoretically show it.
Can anyone gives me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$\begin{split} \left(1 - \frac{c}{1 + L^{2 \gamma}}\right)^{L} &= \exp\left(L\ln\left(1 - \frac{c}{1 + L^{2 \gamma}}\right)\right)\\
&= \exp\left[L\left(- \frac{c}{1 + L^{2 \gamma}} + \underset{L \to +\infty}{o}\left(\frac{1}{1 + L^{2 \gamma}}\right) \right)\right]\\
&= \exp\left[L\left(- \frac{c}{L^{2 \gamma}} + \underset{L \to +\infty}{o}\left(\frac{1}{L^{2 \gamma}}\right) \right)\right]\\
&= \exp\left(- \frac{c}{L^{2 \gamma - 1}} + \underset{L \to +\infty}{o}\left(\frac{1}{L^{2 \gamma - 1}}\right) \right)\\
&= 1 - \frac{c}{L^{2 \gamma - 1}} + \underset{L \to +\infty}{o}\left(\frac{1}{L^{2 \gamma - 1}}\right)
\end{split}$$
Therefore:
$$\begin{split}\left[1 - \left(1 - \frac{c}{1 + L^{2 \gamma}}\right)^{L} \right] L^{2 \gamma - 1} &= \left[1 - \left(1 - \frac{c}{L^{2 \gamma - 1}} + \underset{L \to +\infty}{o}\left(\frac{1}{L^{2 \gamma - 1}}\right)\right)\right]L^{2\gamma - 1}\\
&= c + \underset{L \to +\infty}{o}(1)\end{split}$$
Hence the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I found that I can even got the convergence rate is $\mathcal{O}(L^{1 - 2 \gamma})$